# PDF Html object - Page Change Event Handlers

Tags: javascript, html, dom, pdf, pdf-viewer

So I have a PDF viewer on my page, currently using pdfobject.js, though like many it only creates standard markup for the object.

Example:

```
<object width="100%" height="600" data="/test.pdf#pagemode=thumbs" type="application/pdf"/>
```

Does anyone know of a way to set javascript callbacks for when the page changes in the viewer?
Not sure what details to include, so ask if you need clarification on something.